# How To Un-CamelCase Part Of A String?

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

I have long markdown lists of images like:
`![116-BowlOfApples](./media/116-BowlOfApples.jpg)`

I want to un-CamelCase the caption but not the filename
to get this result:
`![116-Bowl Of Apples](./media/116-BowlOfApples.jpg)`

I'm using:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

and I get

```
![Bowl Of Apples-VI](./media/Bowl Of Apples-VI.jpg)
```

How can I limit this regex to what's in square brackets and leave the filename as is?

Comment: Can you please edit this question and show us the desired result please as it is a bit ambiguous. thanks

Comment: What is the programming language you are using?

Comment: Or, where are you doing this? What tool?

Comment: Wictor, Perl, or whatever else that does lookaround; though I would be happier with Vim. I just saw your answer to replacing chars between square breackets but not between parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: What is `&1 &2`

Comment: $1 and $2 are the captures from the two bracketed searches. they are separated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

Vim solution can look like

```
%s/\v(!\[[^][]*[a-z])@<=([A-Z][^][]*])@=/ /g
```

See the [.NET equivalent regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AE1fnp/1). I am using .NET option since both Vim and .NET regexps support variable-width patterns inside lookbehind assertions.

*Pattern details*:

- `\v` - very magic mode
- `(!\[[^][]*[a-z])@<=` - a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `!\[[^][]*[a-z]` - a `![` substring, then
  - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` chars
  - `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `([A-Z][^][]*])@=` - a location that is immediately followed with

  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
  - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]` - and a `]` char.